# Selected menu item is blank using mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Does not matter which one I choose.

[image]

Comment: Does this happen for CS only? If not, you should probably post such bug reports on [meta.SE] where they also have tags for the app.

Comment: @Raphael yes, only for CS, I have checked the other sites and they have custom backgrounds (working ones). I have obviously checked cache, waited two hours, asked on chat if one could check it as consistent behaviour. I had chance so I checked on friends phone.

Comment: There was also a problem that editing chat message duplicates the message until refresh (but only twice it was posted as separate message), but it is hard to replicate and show.

Comment: With what browser on what device? (Works for me on Android both with Google's browser and Firefox.)

Comment: Thanks for reporting. This should be fixed now.

Comment: @Evil thanks for reporting. we've just pushed bunch of bigger mobile changes. we expect some smaller issues here and there, and looks like this is the first one. i will take care of that!

Comment: @Evil menu font size is the same as it was. we have updated nav couple weeks ago. unless you meant something else.  (yea, we got some phones for tests:p)

Comment: @Paweł Have you seen [this](http://imgur.com/qk9RrsC)? It seems like there was another batch change recently. The "show active" is very low, it sometimes open the first post instead of choose what to show. Also if you could consider salvaging some space from the gray area with answers and upvotes - it would be easier to read. In the [comments below posts](http://imgur.com/W4mSEh5) this is more visible. Mobile Safari. The previous issues (clickable show in the app or message view) are fixed, thank you.